# What exactly does "deriving Functor" do?

Tags: haskell, functor

I'm trying to figure out what exactly are the rules for `deriving Functor` in Haskell.

I've seen [message postings](http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-prime/2007-March/002137.html) about it, and I've seen [test code](http://web.mit.edu/~ezyang/Public/ghc-cmm-09Dec10/testsuite/tests/ghc-regress/deriving/should_compile/drv-functor1.hs) about it, but I can't seem to find official documentation about what the rules are. Can someone please clarify and/or point me to the right place?

Comment: `DeriveFunctor` was first introduced in GHC 6.12, but the release notes for it don't provide any additional clues.

Answer (score 17):

To use `deriving Functor` you must enable the `DeriveFunctor` language pragma and apply it to a polymorphic type which has a covariant final type variable---in other words, a type which admits a valid `Functor` instance. It'll then derive the "obvious" `Functor` instance.

There's been some concern in the past that the derived instance is not as efficient as a hand coded one is, though I cannot seem to find that material.

The algorithm itself was, as far as I could find, [first proposed by Twan Van Laarhoven in 2007](http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-prime/2007-March/002137.html) and makes heavy use of Generic Haskell programming.

Comment: So this message posting is the specification for GHC deriving Functor?

Comment: As far as I know, yes. I don't know that other Haskell implementations have this extension.

Comment: *There's been some concern in the past that the derived instance is not as efficient as a hand coded one is, though I cannot seem to find that material*; Here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52601129/inlining-derived-typeclass-methods

Answer (score 7):

The code that actually does the deed is, unfortunately, a bit on the hairy side. I believe that's largely because earlier, simpler code would sometimes lead to excessive compilation times. Twan van Laarhoven came up with the current code to address this.

The derived `Functor` instance always does the obvious thing. This is usually just fine, but occasionally misses opportunities. For example, suppose I write

```
data Pair a = Pair a a deriving Functor
data Digit a = One a | Two a a deriving Functor
data Queue a =
    Empty
  | Single a
  | Deep !(Digit a) (Queue (Pair a)) !(Digit a) deriving Functor
```

This will generate (in GHC 8.2)

```
instance Functor Queue where
  fmap ...
  x <$ Empty = Empty
  x <$ Single y = Single x
  x <$ Deep pr m sf = Deep (x <$ pr) (fmap (x <$) m) (x <$ sf)
```

It's possible to write that last case much better by hand:

```
  x <$ Deep pr m sf = Deep (x <$ pr) (Pair x x <$ m) (x <$ sf)
```

You can see the actual derived code using `-ddump-deriv`.