# Can the Traversable laws be derived from the fact that every Traversable is also a Functor?

Tags: haskell, theory, traversal

I've been thinking why does the `Traversable` type class require both a `Functor` and `Foldable`, and not just the `Foldable`, since it doesn't use any part of the `Functor`?

```
class (Functor t, Foldable t) => Traversable t where
    traverse  :: Applicative f => (a -> f b) -> t a -> f (t b)
    sequenceA :: Applicative f => t (f a) -> f (t a)
```

Is seems that the laws for Traversable [were not present in the documentation for base 4.6](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.0/docs/Data-Traversable.html), which makes me think that they could be derived from the fact that *every Traversable is a Functor*?

In the [*Essence of the Iterator Pattern* paper (section 5.1)](http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/jeremy.gibbons/publications/iterator.pdf) it states that there are some free theorems for `traverse` which come directly from its type, but the paper doesn't go into depth describing why this is the case.

Where do the `Traversable` [laws as described in the base 4.7 documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Data-Traversable.html) come from?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Basically, any type constructor `* -> *` that's covariant in its argument [is canonically a functor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20336987/what-exactly-does-deriving-functor-do). Since `Applicative f` is obviously covariant, so is `t` for the signature `sequenceA :: t (f a) -> f (t a)` to make sense, hence the `Functor` requirement is essentially redundant. But much like with the long-missing-because-unneeded `Applicative => Monad` superclass, it's not really a good idea to omit such "obvious" requirements, it just leads to code duplication and confusing synonymous functions.