# Why is this functor definition giving me an error?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

```
data PPMImage a = PPMImage {width :: Integer,
                        height :: Integer,
                        magicNumber :: Integer,
                        maxColor :: Integer,
                        pixels :: [a]} deriving (Show)

instance Functor PPMImage where
    fmap f (PPMImage w h m c p) = f PPMImage w h m c (f p)
```

I think I understand the whole wrapping and unwrapping aspect of a functor - [this link](http://adit.io/posts/2013-04-17-functors,_applicatives,_and_monads_in_pictures.html) provided by user MCH helped a lot.

Functions and lists are already functors, but this `PPMImage` I defined does not have the default functor instance. I am trying to define one that will just be applied to the (pixels) array of a `PPMImage` but I keep getting this error:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘[b]’ with actual type ‘b’
  ‘b’ is a rigid type variable bound by
    the type signature for:
      fmap :: forall a b. (a -> b) -> PPMImage a -> PPMImage b
    at New.hs:13:5-8
• In the fifth argument of ‘PPMImage’, namely ‘(f p)’
  In the expression: PPMImage w h m c (f p)
  In an equation for ‘fmap’:
      fmap f (PPMImage w h m c p) = PPMImage w h m c (f p)
• Relevant bindings include
    f :: a -> b (bound at New.hs:13:10)
    fmap :: (a -> b) -> PPMImage a -> PPMImage b (bound at New.hs:13:5)
```

I don't understand why this is happening, wouldn't this functor just unwrap the original `PPMImage`, then apply the function `f`, then rewrap into a new `PPMImage`?

Comment: [Upvotes are more useful than thanks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20336987/what-exactly-does-deriving-functor-do as well.

Comment: Hi @hdizzle! If the answer you've received is satisfactory, I'd reccomend *accepting* it by clicking the tick below its score, otherwise this question looks to be unanswered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should work if you remove the `f` from in front of `PPImage` and add `map` or `fmap` to `f p`. `p` is a list, so you cannot apply `f` directly, it also has to be `fmap`ped over the contents of `p`.

```
instance Functor PPMImage where
    fmap f (PPMImage w h m c p) = PPMImage w h m c (fmap f p)
```

Comment: Don't you need `map f p` instead of `f p`?

Comment: Yes, it could be `map f p` or `fmap f p`.

Comment: Doesn't that f define the function that I am going to use on PPMImage? It doesn't compile for me when removing the f

Comment: @user202729 noted. I had already upvoted your response, however