# Inlining derived typeclass methods

Tags: haskell

Haskell lets you derive typeclass instances, such as:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}

data Foo a = MakeFoo a a deriving (Functor)
```

... but sometimes benchmarks show that performance improves if you manually implement the typeclass instance and annotate the type class method(s) with `INLINE`, like this:

```
data Foo a = MakeFoo a a

instance Functor Foo where
    fmap f (MakeFoo x y) = MakeFoo (f x) (f y)
    {-# INLINE fmap #-}
```

Is there a way to get the best of both worlds?  In other words, is there a way to derive the typeclass instance and also annotate the derived typeclass methods with `INLINE`?

Comment: Somebody has probably written `deriving Functor` using template haskell, which might get you there (maybe it needs a mod).  In fact I think I have one [right here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/deriving-compat).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Though you cannot "reopen" instances in Haskell like you could with classes in dynamic languages, there are ways to ensure that functions will be aggressively inlined whenever possible by passing certain flags to GHC.

> `-fspecialise-aggressively` removes the restrictions about which functions are specialisable. Any overloaded function will be
>   specialised with this flag. This can potentially create lots of
>   additional code.
>
> `-fexpose-all-unfoldings` will include the (optimised) unfoldings of all functions in interface files so that they can be inlined and
>   specialised across modules.
>
> Using these two flags in conjunction will have nearly the same effect
>   as marking every definition as `INLINABLE` apart from the fact that the
>   unfoldings for `INLINABLE` definitions are not optimised.

(Source: https://wiki.haskell.org/Inlining_and_Specialisation#Which_flags_can_I_use_to_control_the_simplifier_and_inliner.3F)

These options will allow the GHC compiler to inline `fmap`. The `-fexpose-all-unfoldings` option, in particular, allows the compiler to expose the internals of `Data.Functor` to the rest of the program for inlining purposes (and it seems to provide the largest performance benefit). Here's a quick & dumb benchmark I threw together:

`functor.hs` contains this code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}
{-# LANGUAGE Strict #-}

data Foo a = MakeFoo a a deriving (Functor)

one_fmap foo = fmap (+1) foo

main = sequence (fmap (\n -> return $ one_fmap $ MakeFoo n n) [1..10000000])
```

Compiled with no arguments:

```
$ time ./functor 

real    0m4.036s
user    0m3.550s
sys 0m0.485s
```

Compiled with `-fexpose-all-unfoldings`:

```
$ time ./functor

real    0m3.662s
user    0m3.258s
sys 0m0.404s
```

Here's the `.prof` file from this compile, to show that the call to `fmap` is indeed getting inlined:

```
    Sun Oct  7 00:06 2018 Time and Allocation Profiling Report  (Final)

       functor +RTS -p -RTS

    total time  =        1.95 secs   (1952 ticks @ 1000 us, 1 processor)
    total alloc = 4,240,039,224 bytes  (excludes profiling overheads)

COST CENTRE MODULE SRC              %time %alloc

CAF         Main   <entire-module>  100.0  100.0


                                                                     individual      inherited
COST CENTRE MODULE                SRC             no.     entries  %time %alloc   %time %alloc

MAIN        MAIN                  <built-in>       44          0    0.0    0.0   100.0  100.0
 CAF        Main                  <entire-module>  87          0  100.0  100.0   100.0  100.0
 CAF        GHC.IO.Handle.FD      <entire-module>  84          0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF        GHC.IO.Encoding       <entire-module>  77          0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF        GHC.Conc.Signal       <entire-module>  71          0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF        GHC.IO.Encoding.Iconv <entire-module>  58          0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
```

Compiled with `-fspecialise-aggressively`:

```
$ time ./functor

real    0m3.761s
user    0m3.300s
sys 0m0.460s
```

Compiled with both flags:

```
$ time ./functor

real    0m3.665s
user    0m3.213s
sys 0m0.452s
```

These little benchmarks are by no means representative of what the performance (or filesize) will like in real code, but it definitely shows that you can force the GHC compiler to inline `fmap` (and that it really can have non-negligible effects on performance).

Comment: This is good enough for my use case since if I want to restrict the scope of this I can split the type and its instances into a separate Haskell module and then add either  `{-# OPTIONS_GHC -fexpose-all-unfoldings #-}` or `{-# OPTIONS_GHC -fspecialise-aggressively #-}` to the top of the module

Comment: @GabrielGonzalez those annotations are news to me. Thanks for that! Also, a note: you can still mark large functions `NOINLINE` to ensure that they don't get inlined and destroy the filesize.